# mongoengine - Use QuerySet as ReferenceField

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Based on this [tutorial](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html):

```
from mongoengine import *

connect('tumblelog')

class User(Document):
    email = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    first_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=50)

class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    content = StringField()
    name = StringField(max_length=120)

class Post(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    author = ReferenceField(User, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
    tags = ListField(StringField(max_length=30))
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

class TextPost(Post):
    content = StringField()

class ImagePost(Post):
    image_path = StringField()

class LinkPost(Post):
    link_url = StringField()


def main():
    john = User(email='jdoe@example.com', first_name='John', last_name='Doe')
    john.save()
    john_from_db = User.objects(email='jdoe@example.com')
    post1 = TextPost(title='Fun with MongoEngine', author = john_from_db)
    post1.content = 'Took a look at MongoEngine today, looks pretty cool.'
    post1.tags = ['mongodb','mongoengine']
    post1.save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get this error on post1.save():

```
mongoengine.base.ValidationError: ValidationError(A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef or documents: ['author'])
```

I tried adding the dbref=True/False option in the ReferenceField declaration but it didn't fix anything.  The object john is of type User, while john_from_db is a QuerySet.  Surely I'm missing something here, how do you get an object from the db and use it in another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call first() on the QuerySet to get the first record that matches the query e.g.

```
john_from_db = User.objects(email='jdoe@example.com').first()
```